# buenas tardes, alguien tiene una idea de como resolver este problema

Tags: html, django, ccs

tengo una template Index en donde muestro un listado de categorias y otras cosas, por otro lado tengo otro template donde muestro este listado de categorias con algunos detalles, como hago para q en el index cuando de clic en alguna categoria este me envie para el template de categorias pero que se ubique extactamente en el lugar en el q aparece esta categoria seleccionada:
listado index HTML:

```
{% for cat in category %}
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="service-item">
                        <a href="{% url 'category-list' cat.id %}">
                            <h4>{{ cat.name }}</h4>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Listado en el template Categorias HTML:

```
 {% for cat in category %}
<section class="lunch-menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="lunch-menu-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <h2>Menú de {{ cat.name }}</h2>
                            <div id="owl-lunch" class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-lunch">
                                {% for prod in cat.product_set.all %}
                                    <div class="item col-md-12">
                                        <div class="food-item">
                                            <img height="133px" src="/{% thumbnail prod.image 230x0 crop %}" alt="">
                                            <div class="price">${{ prod.price }}</div>
                                            <div class="text-content">
                                                <h4>{{ prod.name }}</h4>
                                                <p>{{ prod.descripcion|safe|truncatechars:100 }}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="right-image">
                                <img height="540px" width="363px" src="/{% thumbnail cat.image 600x0 crop %}" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
         {% endfor %}
```

mi views:

```
def category_list(request, id):
    category= models.Category.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'category': category})
```

mi url:

```
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('category-list/<int:id>', views.category_list, name='category-list')
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: ya resolvi, solo tenia q pasar en el index el href= {{URL}} #cat_id y luego en el listado de categorias en el encabezado id= cat_id. Gracias

Comment: Ponlo como solución abajo, en el campo Tu Respuesta. Le va a servir a otros con la misma pregunta y podrás marcarla como aceptada en unas horas :)